# The meaning of "the time is long past that"?

Tags: expressions

I want to know the meaning of **the time is long past that** in the following sentence:

> In any case, the time is long past that he know his heritage and his place in the world. I’ve gone along with this fiction for far longer than I should have. But now . . .

Comment: He should have been told a long time ago about his heritage and his place in the world.

Comment: [ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/318159/what-does-its-long-past-time-that-mean)

Comment: Please tell us where you found this sentence. It doesn't seem quite natural English to me.

Comment: It's quite unclear. Much less confusing is _It's long past time for him to learn about_. Using _know_ instead of _learn_ makes it unclear whether he's sposta know already or whether he's still ignorant. Make it clear which one you mean.

Comment: f u @StuartF stuart farty

Answer (score 1):

> In any case, the time is long past [that he know his heritage and his
> place in the world].

It's a little awkward, but "that" is the head of a prepositional phrase modifying "time".

Comment: A prepositional phrase?

Answer (score 0):

It could be rephrased as "He should already know his heritage and his place in the world."

The phrasing is a bit formal in the quote. If one were to describe the time when someone "experiences" or "knows" something on a timeline, you could describe it as a "time" you are "past". In this case long past.